# Count the number of zero digit in an integer number?

Tags: algorithm, math

I wonder if there is a way to count the number of zero digit in an integer number by using only these operations: +, -, * and /
Others operations such as cast, div, mod, ... are not allowed.

Input:  16085021
Output: 2

Comment: By `/` do you mean integer division (e.g. so that `32 / 10 = 3` rather than `32 / 10 = 3.2`)? Also -- since this seems to be homework, what have you tried?

Comment: The / operation means 32 / 10 = 3.2. I'm new in programming domain and it just a small exercise to try. Thanks.

Comment: What about comparisons? Is `<` or `==` allowed?

Comment: You could determine the length of the number just by comparing to 1, 10, 100, 1000, etc. Then with a simple `for` loop you could figuring out the value of the high-ordering digit, again by using comparisons. Then, since you know the length of the number and the high-order digit you could subtract off the high-order digit and recursively apply the algorithm to the remaining number.

Comment: About the comparison, only == is allowed.

Comment: @David, shouldn't your question list *all* restrictions?

Comment: Are bitwise operators allowed?

Answer (score 4):

It is a major restriction that numbers cannot be compared in a way to know that one is less than the other, and only equality checks can be done.

In my opinion that means there is nothing much else you can do than repeatedly add 1 to a variable until it hits a target (`n`) and derive from that what the least significant digit is of the original number `n`. This is of course terribly slow and not scalable, but it works in theory.

Here is a demo in Python using only `==`, `+`, `-` and `/`:

```py
n = 16085021

count = 0
while True:
    # find out what least significant digit is
    digit = 0
    i = 0
    while True:
        if n == i:
            break
        digit = digit + 1
        if digit == 10:
            digit = 0
        i = i + 1
    # count any zero digit
    if digit == 0:
        count = count + 1
    # shift that digit out of n
    n = (n - digit) / 10
    if n == 0:
        break

print(count)  # 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Modulo can be implemented with subtractions: `a % b = subtract b from a until you end up with something < b and that's the result`. You say we can only use the `==` comparison operator, but we are only interested in `modulo 10`, so we can just check equality to `0`, `1`, ..., `9`.

```
def modulo10WithSubtractions(a):
    if a == 0 || a == 1 || ... || a == 9:
        return a
    while True:
        a = a - b
        if a == 0 || a == 1 || ... || a == 9:
            return a
```

Integer division by 10 can be implemented in a similar fashion: `a // 10 = add 10 to itself as many times as possible without exceeding a`.

```
def div10WithAdditions(a):
    if a == 0 || a == 1 || ... || a == 9:
        return 0

    k = 0
    while True:
        k += 1
        if a - k*10 == 0 || a - k*10 == 1 || ... || a - k*10 == 9:
            return k
```

Then we can basically do the classical algorithm:

```
count = 0
while True:
    lastDigit = modulo10WithSubtractions(a)
    if lastDigit == 0:
        count += 1
    a = div10WithAdditions(a)
    if a == 0:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Asuuming `/` means integer division, then this snippet does the job.

```
int zeros = 0;
while(num > 0){
  if(num / 10 == (num + 9) / 10){
    zeros++;
  }
  num /= 10;
}
```

Comment: In case / is integer division, your snippet code work correctly. With float division (32 / 10 = 3.2), my opinion is that there is no way to get the job done.

Comment: @David With float division and only equality, there is no help for it but to use repeated addition to find the value and its base 10 representation.  Doable, but inefficient and not how you'd want to program anything.